# Preposition for "going to your house"

Tags: usage, preposition

> Können Sie mir sagen, wie ich vom Flughafen nach Ihrem Haus mit der U-Bahn fahren kann?

Should it be "nach" or "zu" here? I'm not sure because we say "Ich gehe nach Hause" and "Ich bleibe zu Hause", but "zu" commonly denotes direction toward a place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's "zu Ihrem Haus":

> Können Sie mir bitte sagen, wie ich vom Flughaufen (mit öffentlichen Verkehrsmitteln) zu Ihrem Haus komme?

"Nach Hause" and "zu Hause" are both correct, but in this case you are talking about the actual house of somebody. Let's try with some other landmark:

> Können Sie mir bitte sagen, wie ich vom Flughaufen zum Rathaus komme? ... zur Oper komme? ... zum Hauptplatz komme?

Comment: While correct, I don't think "zu Ihrem Haus" would be used by a native. A plain "zu Ihnen" or maybe "zu Ihnen nach hause" sounds more like it. (It's not often that you are invited into the home of a person you address formally, but well.)

Comment: No offense (and none taken), but what exactly do you take me for, then? I find nothing wrong with this sentence, depending on circumstances as always.

Comment: Maybe it's a regional thing, then. I see that you hail from Austria (?) while I'm from north of the Main -- that's far away, language-wise. My comment applies to German German as I know it; Austrian German may have different conventions.

Answer (score 3):

"Nach Hause" ist richtig, das ist ein fester Begriff. Das bleibt auch bestehen, wenn Du den Eigentümer nennst: "zu jemandem nach Hause" oder "zu jemandem ins Büro".

Wenn Du das Haus nicht im Sinne von "nach Hause" sondern als konkrete Ortsangabe verwendest, steht es mit "zu": zu Deinem Haus, zu ihrem Geschäft, zu meinem Auto.

Ist die Ortsangabe weiter gefasst, verwendet man "nach", zum Beispiel für Städte und Länder: nach England (aber in die USA), nach Berlin.

Answer (score 3):

In short "nach Ihrem Haus" is wrong. You should replace it by "zu Ihnen nach Hause".

"zu Ihrem Haus" would be correct as well if you just mean the plain building. In contrast to that "zu Ihnen nach Hause" means the home of somebody, where you feel comfortable, etc... and this is what you usually use in your context.