# Ins oder nach Disneyland?

Tags: grammar, preposition

Im Sommer fahre ich ins Disneyland.

Wenn Disneyland eine Stadt wäre, dann wäre es »nach Disneyland«, aber ich sah in einigen Kontexten, dass man »nach« mit dem Substantiv Disneyland benutzt. Ist es besser »nach«  oder »ins« zu benutzen?

Comment: Related: [Using “nach” or “zu” for landmarks and similar](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/17671/9551)

Comment: Ist Disneyland eine Stadt? Wohl kaum! Es ist ein Freizeitpark. Man kann den Namen aber behandeln, als sei es ernst, und wie nach Holland auch nach Disneyland fahren - vielleicht bevorzugt bei Kindern, wenn die das für ein echtes Land halten. Sonst ins Disneyland oder zum Disneyland (Parkplatz/Bahnhof außerhalb?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nach --> In die Richtung.

Normally you go there to visit it and go inside it.

So you'd say:"Ich gehe ins Disney-land"