# Preposition "bei" and "in" to express "in/at a place"

Tags: preposition, dative

In case of "WO", when do we use "bei + dativ" and/or "in + dativ"?
What is the difference?

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/using-nach-or-zu-for-landmarks-and-similar

Comment: Think about the meanings -> "bei" means "by" and "in" is "in/at". As such, you would use "bei" when you want to say you are by someone or even by a place. However, if you are in/at a place you would use the word "in". It wouldn't make sense to say you are "in" a person.

Answer (score 1):

Question/Frage:

> "Wo bist du?"
>
> "Where are you?"

Answer/Antwort:

> "Ich bin bei Peter." (I'm at Peter's (place)).

Case used for persons/people mostly.

> "Ich bin in der Bar." (I'm in/at the bar).

Case mostly used for places.

That should pretty much sum up what you are asking, I guess.

Comment: In Köln, bei Aldi, in der Schule, beim Saubermachen...

Answer (score 1):

"In" refers to being inside *"places."* Ich bin *im* Restaurant. I am *in* the Restaurant.

"Bei" refers to being part of, or a member of, an *institution* or a *group*. A better translation than "in" is "with." Ich bin *bei* der Uni. I am *with* the University (e.g. as a professor). On the other hand,"Ich bin *in* der Uni" would mean, I am *inside* the University (building).

A tricky phrase is "Ich bin bei Tom." In German, that means, "I am with Tom" (probably at Tom's house.)

But an English speaker might say, "I am at/in Tom's" (house).

Answer (score 1):

### in + Dativ

<sup>(note, that *»in + dem«* becomes *»im«*)</sup>
»In« is used, if something is located ...

- inside a building

  > Ich bin **im** Haus. (= Ich bin ***in*** dem Haus.)
  >   I'm in the house.
  >
  > Lisa ist **in** der Schule.
  >   Lisa is in school.
- in a country or continent

  > Ernst ist gerade **in** Japan.
  >   Ernst is currently in Japan.
  >
  > Kenya liegt **in** Afrika.
  >   Kenya is located in Africa.
- in a region

  > Ich mache Urlaub **in** den Alpen.
  >   I'm on holiday in the Alps.
  >
  > Karl lebt **in** der Stadt.
  >   Karl lives in the city.
- in a street, alley, ...

  > Ich bin jetzt **in** der Grillparzerstraße.
  >   I am now in Grillparzerstrasse.
  >
  > Erika wohnt **in** der Maigasse.
  >   Erika lives in Maigasse.

---

### bei + Dativ

<sup>(note, that *»bei + dem«* becomes *»beim«*)</sup>
»In« is used, if ...

- a location is located near a city

  > Monika arbeitet in Baden **bei** Wien.
  >   Monika works in Baden near Vienna.
  >
  > Helmut kauft Tickets für den Freizeitpark **bei** Leipzig.
  >   Helmut buys tickets for the Freizeitpark near Leipzig.
- something is located near something else

  > Ich meine die Bank **bei** den drei Eichen.
  >   I mean the bench at the three oaks.
  >
  > Kochlöffel finden Sie **bei** den Haushaltswaren.
  >   Cooking spoons can be found in the household goods.
- someone is located near another person

  > Eugen ist gerade **beim** Chef. (= Eugen ist gerade **bei** dem Chef.)
  >   Eugen is currently at the boss.
  >
  > Ich war gestern **bei** Christa.
  >   I visited Christa yesterday.
- someone works at a company

  > Lukas arbeitet **bei** der Post.
  >   Lukas works at the post office.
  >
  > Maria arbeitet **bei** einer Bank.
  >   Maria works at a Bank.