# In der <Straßenname> vs. auf der <Straßenname>

Tags: preposition

In der Schularbeit meiner Tochter hat die Lehrerin eine Überschrift von

> Unfall auf der Foostraße

zu

> Unfall in der Foostraße

korrigiert.

Vom Gefühl würde ich sagen, dass beides zulässig ist, aber eine wirkliche Regel konnte ich nicht finden.

Ist "auf" eventuell dialektal oder umgangssprachlich?

Mir geht es nicht nur um Unfälle, wo man argumentieren könnte, dass die ja in der Mitte der Fahrbahn stattfinden, sondern auch zum Beispiel um Geschäfte, die sich auf einer Straße befinden.

Comment: Mich würde noch interessieren, wie "an der Straße" dazu passt. Grade bei Geschäften finde ich das ebenfalls passend.

Comment: Verwandte [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/39893/1696).

Comment: @xyldke [passt dazu](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/an-in-oder-an-der-stra%c3%9fe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Eine wirklich interessante Frage, über die ich - als Muttersprachler - noch nie nachgedacht habe. Intuitiv meine ich, dass man nie sagen würde: "Es gab einen Unfall in der Straße" (also allgemein, ohne konkrete Bezeichnung), sondern immer "auf". Umgekehrt halte ich die Formulierung: "Es gab einen Unfall auf der Foostraße" für ungewöhnlich, aber ich würde vermutlich nicht mal zucken, wenn es jemand sagte. Ähnlich verhält es sich mit "Ich traf X neulich in der Foostraße / auf der Straße." Geschäfte wiederum sind nie auf der Straße, es sei denn, man verkauft etwas auf dem Bürgersteig.

Comment: *In* der Foostraße kann man wohnen, *auf* der Straße nur verkehren (oder verunfallen). Es ist aber ohne weiteres auch der umgekehrte Gebrauch verständlich.

Answer (score 4):

Im Fall des ersten Beispiels lässt sich imho für beides sinnvoll argumentieren. *(Wie du es mit der Frage nach dem Ort des Unfalls getan hast.)*

Bei

> Essengehen im "Ristorante A Mano" **in / auf** der Foostraße

empfinde ich *"auf"* als **nicht** "standardsprachlich". Konkrete Regeln gibt es aber meines Wissens nach nicht. (Die Verwendung von Präpositionen ist ja im stetigen Wandel)

Das Geschäft ist offensichtlich nicht auf der Straße (im Sinne einer Fahrbahn). Der Unfall ereignete sich jedoch wahrscheinlich dort. Ich empfinde *"in"* im Kontext einer Straße als allgemeiner. Damit wird nicht nur die Fahrbahn, sondern auch der potentielle Gehweg, Pflanzen und auch die Häuser selbst gemeint und ist damit mehrdeutig. (Ähnliche Einschätzungen auch [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/an-in-oder-an-der-stra%C3%9Fe/43738#43738) oder in der von @guidot [verlinkten Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/39952/46642) )

---

Ich hätte es aber nicht "korrigiert", sondern alternativ angeboten, sonst kommt schlechte Stimmung auf ;)

Answer (score 4):

Bei Verwendung des Straßennamens würde ich auch nicht "auf" benutzen, sondern "in". "Ein Unfall auf der Goethestraße" klingt nicht komplett falsch, aber doch zumindest ungeschliffener als "... in der Goethestraße". Ohne Straßenname ist es dagegen oft "auf der Straße" (im Gegensatz z.B. zu "auf dem Bürgersteig" oder "auf dem Radweg", oder auch in Ausdrücken wie "Sie war wieder den ganzen Tag auf der Straße" oder "Er lebte auf der Straße").

Eine (leider nicht besonders aussagekräftige) Quelle habe ich nur hier gefunden: https://learngerman.dw.com/de/lokale-pr%C3%A4positionen-in-an/l-40375386/gr-40376309

Ausnahmen gibt es, wenn eigentlich vom Sinn "auf der Straße" gemeint ist, aber man die Straße genauer bezeichnen muss oder möchte: "Der Unfallbeteiligte A. näherte sich auf der Schillerstraße aus Richtung Westen kommend mit hoher Geschwindigkeit."

Andere Wörter sind natürlich sowieso etwas anderes: auf der Reeperbahn, auf der Autobahn, auf der Königsallee, auf dem Boulevard des Champs-Elysées.

Answer (score 2):

[Laut Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+der+Bahnhofstra%C3%9Fe%2Cauf+der+Bahnhofstra%C3%9Fe&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=1&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20der%20Bahnhofstra%C3%9Fe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauf%20der%20Bahnhofstra%C3%9Fe%3B%2Cc0) ist "in der Foostraße" allgemein deutlich gebräuchlicher als "auf der Foostraße". (Wenn man "Unfall" hinzufügt, finden sich komischerweise keine Ergebnisse.)

Allerdings finden sich im Web für ["Unfall auf der Bahnhofstraße"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Unfall+auf+der+Bahnhofstra%C3%9Fe%22) ähnlich viele Treffer wie ["Unfall in der Bahnhofstraße"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Unfall+in+der+Bahnhofstra%C3%9Fe%22). Die Trefferzahlen sind hier sicherlich mit Vorsicht zu genießen, aber da viele von den Suchergebnissen mit "auf" auf Zeitungen zu finden sind, würde ich sagen, dass "auf" sicherlich eine akzeptable Alternative zu "in" ist.

Das "auf" rechtfertigt sich für mich auch dadurch, dass ein Unfall ja normalerweise auf der Straße selbst (also der Fahrbahn) passiert.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde das vom Inhalt des Textes abhängig machen.

Geht es im Text weniger um den Unfallhergang, sondern um die Folgen, bspw. die Erregung und das Erlebnis aus Sicht des Kindes, stehe ich bei der Lehrkraft. Ein alternativer Titel wäre ja "Neulich bei uns in der Foostraße", und das ist im Kern eine geläufige Floskel.

"Auf" ist m.E.n. nur zu bevorzugen, wenn als Alternativtitel "Neulich mitten auf der Foostraße" passender wäre, sprich wenn sich der Text kaum je vom Geschehen *auf* der Strasse löst.