# Dativpräpositionen – how to say "I am going to Anna's House"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, preposition, dative

I'm a total beginner and I'd like to cover one of the *Dativpräpositionen* basics in German.

Which of the following sentences is the most correct and complete form of saying "I am going to Anna's house"?

> 1. *Ich gehe bei Anna nach Hause.*
> 2. *Ich gehe zu Anna nach Hause.*

Or is none of the above sentences correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preposition *to* in *to go to someone/something* is (usually) translated as *zu* or *nach*, depending on the target. There were already quite a few question on that, which should fully answer your question.

- [Using “nach” or “zu” for landmarks and similar](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17671/1224)
- [Richtungen und Ziele: Wir fahren “nach / in / zu / an” [Artikel] XYZ?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/8479/1224)
- [Preposition for “going to your house”](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/12154/1224)

The last question is actually identical to your very question.

Correct is:

> Ich gehe zu jemandem nach Hause.

You also find some examples in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehen#Bedeutung4a).

Comment: Thank you @Em1, that and the references answer my question. I indeed treat *das Haus* as an exceptional target with dative, e.g. as opposed to *Ich gehe zu der Post*, I was confused about going to a specific person's house.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna say `I am going to Anna's house`, you say :

> Ich gehe zu Annas Haus.

Or simply :

Ich gehe zu Anna.

I am going to correct your sentence in number 1. It should be :

> Ich bin bei Anna (zu Hause).

It means that you are at her house.

Comment: @DerPolzglott33, *Ich bin bei Anna (zu Hause)* doesn't correct the sentence, it's changing its meaning (static vs. dynamic situation)

Comment: "Ich gehe zu Annas Haus" is a correct sentence, but it really just means that you are going to the house which is Anna's, it neither implies that she will be there or even that she lives there. I think this is different from the use of "Anna's house" in English (where it may afaik even be used if it isn't even a house).

Answer (score 2):

Number two is correct.

> Ich gehe zu Anna nach Hause.

Trust me, I am a native German.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but beeing a native speaker is no reason to trust you. Other users will vote up your answer when it is good, and they will vote it down if it is bad or wrong. So after a while everybody can read the quality of your answer from it's score. There is no need to tell something that most people can't prove and so could be a lie

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: As a learner, I'm **very** interested in knowing whether an answer is written by a native speaker.  I know that it doesn't guarantee correctness (e.g. there can be regional differences), but it's nevertheless one of the most useful pieces of information.  The only possible motivations to lie here are (1) ego stroking (via Imaginary Internet Points) and (2) trolling.  But there are easier ways of doing both, so the probability is very low.

Comment: @j_random_hacker thank you for your support :) But I have to admit that I did a mistake. Like the first comment says, I wrote "nach hause" instead of "nach Hause", thats because I have troubles with the upper and lower caseing(?) eventhrough I`m German. But this is also the reason I love the english language, you can write nearly evrything in lower case, and thats what I do in german too sometimes..